# Database hosts close connection after some time of inactivity

Tags: postgresql, hosting, psql, node-postgres, supabase

Currently I use supabase PostgreSQL hosting for my site and node-postgres to make queries. After some time (about 5-7 min) of inactivity connection is terminated and it's impossible to get/send data to DB. It is not node-Postgres problem, because connection has same behaviour even if you make queries from psql terminal.

I even tried to change hosting provider, but second provider (bit.io) had the same problem.

I came up with idea to make interceptor function that catches `connection_error` and makes request again. But I don't think that it is the most efficient approach.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please quote the precise error message found both on the client side, and on the server side (found in the PostgreSQL log file)

Comment: Maybe the problem is on your side, or your ISP.  That would explain why both hosting providers experience it.  Can you just throw up an AWS EC2 machine (or whatever provider you have handy) and launch a dormant connection there and see if it times out?

Comment: @jjanes Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly.

Comment: @jjanes I tried VPN and It does not disconnect any more. It looks like this problem is due to my ISP